# How to make the add and subtrack quantity button in a for loop work well in php

Tags: php

I am designing an ecommerce in php site and i am making all the products alongside with the buttons display with a for loop in the cart page i did a function to add and subtract the quantity of an item but the problem is that the when one button is clicked it works for all of the products instead one of the specific product it was clicked for. please how do i rectify this

```
<?php
             echo"<table border='1' class='doctortable1'>";
                
               $val1="SELECT * FROM cart where idnum = '$sesid' ";

               $val2=mysqli_query($db,$val1);

                $val3=mysqli_num_rows($val2);
                
                if($val3 != 0)
                {
                    function minusqnty( $con1e){
              $user="root";
                $pass="";
                $db="aj";
                $db = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die ("could not connect");
                             
                $qnty1 = "SELECT * FROM cart  WHERE oid = '$con1e'";
                             
                 $qnty2 = mysqli_query($db,$qnty1);
            
            $qnty3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qnty2);
                             $qnty4 = $qnty3['quantity'];
                            $qnty5 = $qnty4 - 1;
                             
                //updating quantity record
                $qnty6 = "UPDATE cart SET quantity ='$qnty5' WHERE oid = $con1e";
                             mysqli_query($db,$qnty6);
                             
                     }
                         
                         function plusqnty( $con1e){
              $user="root";
                $pass="";
                $db="aj";
                $db = new mysqli('localhost',$user,$pass,$db) or die ("could not connect");
                             
                $qnty1 = "SELECT * FROM cart  WHERE oid = '$con1e'";
                             
                 $qnty2 = mysqli_query($db,$qnty1);
            
            $qnty3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qnty2);
                             $qnty4 = $qnty3['quantity'];
                            $qnty5 = $qnty4 + 1;
                             
                //updating quantity record
                $qnty6 = "UPDATE cart SET quantity ='$qnty5' WHERE oid = $con1e";
                             mysqli_query($db,$qnty6);
                             
                     }
                    
                    
                     
                     for($x=1; $x<=$val3; $x++ ){
                         
                         
                         $con1c = mysqli_fetch_array($con1a);
                         
                         $con1d = $con1c['photo'];
                         
                         $con1e = $con1c['oid'];
                         
                         echo"<tr class = 'sectionc1'>";
                         
                         echo"<td class='sectionc1a'>"."<img src= $con1d class= 'sectionc1a1' >"."</td>";
                         
                         //function for quantity button
                         
                            if(array_key_exists('minusqnty',$_POST))
                {
                        minusqnty($con1e);
                    }
                         
                          if(array_key_exists('plusqnty',$_POST))
                {
                        plusqnty($con1e);
                    }
                         
                          echo"<td class='sectionc1b'>".
                              
                              "
                              <table class='sectionc1b1' >
                              <tr>
                              <td>Name: " .$con1c['name']."</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td>Price: " .$con1c['price']." naira</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td>Quantity:   "."
                              <td>
                              <div class='sectionc1b2'>
                            
                    <form method='post'>". "<input type='submit' class='sectionc1b2a' name='minusqnty' id='minusqnty' value='-' />".      "</form>
                              
                              <div class='sectionc1b2b'>" .$con1c['quantity']."</div>
                              
                      <form method='post'>". "<input type='submit' class='sectionc1b2c' name='plusqnty' id='plusqnty' value='+' />".      "</form>
                              
                              </div></td>
                              "."</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td><a href='' class='sectionc1b2d'>Remove Item</a></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td><a href='' class='sectionc1b2d'>Read all about the product</a></td>
                              </tr>
                              </table> 
                              "
                              
                              ."</td>";
                         
                         echo"</tr>";
                         
                    
                        //break;
                    }
                    /*while($con1c = mysqli_fetch_array($con1a)){
                        $con1d = $con1c['photo'];
                         
                         echo"<tr class = 'sectionc1'>";
                         
                         echo"<td class='sectionc1a'>"."<div class='sectionc1a1'>
                         $con1d;
                         </div>"."</td>";
                         
                          echo"<td class='sectionc1b'>"."sdsds"."</td>";
                         
                         echo"</tr>";
                   }*/
              
               
               }
                else
                {
                    echo "<h1>You have no items in your cart <h1>";
                   
                }
        echo"</table>";
        ?>
    </div>
```

this is the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE553.png)

Answer (score 0):

This line here is your problem, you are selecting all items and removing them:

```
$qnty1 = "SELECT * FROM cart  WHERE oid = '$con1e'";
```

This line of code below is correct and doesn't need the line above:

```
$qnty6 = "UPDATE cart SET quantity ='$qnty5' WHERE oid = $con1e";
```

the * means ALL